# Laravel: call static function inside blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I found very strange situation. I have a collection with some results and I wanna grab for each of that results the saved in cache information. For that I have a Cache class, which has one static function get(). Unfortunately I am not receiving anything when I call it in the foreach loop of my Blade template.

```
@foreach($prognoses as $sport_prognose)
    <?php
        $pr = Cache::get(Config::get('variables.cache.prediction'), ['id' => $sport_prognose['id']]);
        print_r($pr);
        die();
    ?>
@endforeach
```

If I call the same function inside the Controller is display me the needed information, but not as in the example above.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cache()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-cache) and [`config()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-config) and other [global helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#available-methods) instead of facades to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey for your response. The Cache class is my so i need to call it static, but i have changed the Config to config()-> and it still does not give me the information i need. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If `Cache` class is yours, try to use full namespace, like `\App\My\Cache::get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the blade template, you can write something like this:

```
{{ $pc::getProducts($ship->products) }}
```

Notice the use of variables. Obviously getProducts is a static method inside the controller, and $ship->products is a variable coming from an array. Let's make it simple: suppose $ship->products is 1, and getProducts is this:

```
 static function getProducts($id) { echo "id is $id; }
```

If you ran this script, you'd get an error because the template lacks the value of $pc. How do you get around this? You need to pass the value of $this to the template:

```
 return View::make('shipping.index')->with(['pc' => $this, 'shipping' => $shippings);
```

Here shipping.index is the template, and pc is getting a value of $this, which allows $pc to get accceess to getProducts inside the blade template.